# $\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\frac{k^2(e^{-it\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}-e^{it\sqrt{k^2+m^2}})\sin(\theta)}{e^{-ikx\cos{\theta}}\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}d\theta dk$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\frac{k^2\left(e^{-it\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}-e^{it\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\right)\sin(\theta)}{e^{-ikx\cos{\theta}}\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}d\theta dk$$

I saw this Integral at Quora, and I have not idea how to evaluate it. Therefore, I thought of posting it here.

How do we Evaluate this?

Comment: Is there any context for this? Variable $t$ is not usually used for an arbitrary constant.

Comment: One obvious substitution is $k=m\sinh u$, which, along with the presence of $e^{ikx~\cosh\theta}$, leads us to suspect that [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) might be involved.

Comment: i don't know if it helps much, but the theta integral is almost trivial...

Comment: I suppose the end-result will be a complex function of the variables $x$ and $t$, which sounds like a one-dimensional space-time (QM) problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can write:

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\frac{k^2\left(e^{-it\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}-e^{it\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}\right)\sin(\theta)}{e^{-ikx\cos{\theta}}\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}d\theta dk$$

As:

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\frac{k^2\left(-2 i \sin{(t \sqrt{k^2+m^2})}\right)\sin(\theta)}{e^{-ikx\cos{\theta}}\sqrt{k^2+m^2}}d\theta dk = \int_0^\infty \frac{k^2\left(-2 i \sin{(t\sqrt{k^2+m^2})}\right)}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} \int_0^\pi e^{ikx\cos{\theta}} \sin(\theta) d\theta dk = \int_0^\infty \frac{k^2\left(-4 i \sin{(t\sqrt{k^2+m^2})}\right)}{\sqrt{k^2+m^2}} \frac{\sin{k x}}{k x} dk=\int_0^\infty -4 ik^2 t sinc{(t\sqrt{k^2+m^2})} sinc(k x) dk= -4 t i \int_0^\infty k^2 sinc{(t\sqrt{k^2+m^2})} sinc(k x) dk $$ 
Now by using the relationship:
$$sinc{(t\sqrt{k^2+m^2})}= \prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{(t\sqrt{k^2+m^2})^2}{n^2 \pi^2})$$
And:
$$sinc{(k x)}= \prod_{j=1}^{+\infty}(1-\frac{(k x)^2}{j^2 \pi^2})$$
We can write
$$-4 t i \int_0^\infty k^2 sinc{(t\sqrt{k^2+m^2})} sinc(k x) dk = -4 t i \lim_{\phi \rightarrow +\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{+\infty} \int_0^\phi k^2 (1-\frac{(t\sqrt{k^2+m^2})^2}{n^2 \pi^2}) (1-\frac{(k x)^2}{j^2 \pi^2}) = -4 t i \lim_{\phi \rightarrow +\infty}\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{+\infty} \left[ \frac{\phi^3}{3}(1-(\frac{m t}{n \pi})^2)+\frac{\phi^5}{5}((\frac{m t x}{j n \pi^2})^2-(\frac{t}{n \pi})^2-(\frac{x}{j \pi})^2)+\frac{\phi^7}{7}(\frac{t x }{j n \pi^2})^2\right]$$
Which seems to diverge

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed form for this definite integral because it is not convergent.

[image]